# "Parameter index out of range" error when doing authentication with login form

Tags: java, sql, angularjs, jdbc

I am trying to get email and password from user (Auth class) and check whether this email and password exist or not with the Customer class. I am using HTML, Angular.js, Java and SQL. I am using the JDBC driver. This is the error that I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

This is my java code for CustomerDAO class:

```
public boolean authenticated(Auth auth) throws AppException {
    Connection con = DBUtil.connectToDB();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement customerPreparedStatement=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    ResultSet newRs=null;
    Customer customer=new Customer();

    try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO auth(EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        //if((customer.getEmail().equals(auth.getEmail())) && (customer.getPassword().equals(auth.getPassword())))
        ps.setString(1, auth.getEmail());
        ps.setString(2, auth.getPassword());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        //geting generated key
        rs= ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        customerPreparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer.EMAIL, customer.PASSWORD, auth.EMAIL, auth.PASSWORD FROM customer,auth WHERE customer.EMAIL=auth.email AND customer.PASSWORD=auth.PASSWORD");
        newRs=customerPreparedStatement.executeQuery();

        customerPreparedStatement.setString(1, customer.getEmail());
        customerPreparedStatement.setString(2, customer.getPassword());

        if(auth.getEmail().equals(customer.getEmail()) && auth.getPassword().equals(customer.getPassword())){
    //  if(customerPreparedStatement){  
            while(rs.next()){
                customer.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                auth.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                auth.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));

    //          System.out.print());
            }
            return true;
        }else {
            System.out.print("user doesn't exist");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AppException("Error in authentication", e.getCause());
    }finally{
        DBUtil.closeResources(ps, rs, con);
    }
}
```

What logic should I use?

What change should I make?

Comment: Read the error message. What do you think it might be trying to tell you?

Comment: number of parameter that is passed, is 0. but why? I am passing parameters email and password here.

Comment: No, that's not what it says. It says you're trying to pass parameters into something that doesn't expect them.

Comment: @user3443889 check my answer. I suspect I've identified the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**customerPreparedStatement** has no parameter slots (**?** symbols), but you supply parameters.

The prepared statement for getting customers does not have parameters:

```
customerPreparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer.EMAIL, customer.PASSWORD, auth.EMAIL, auth.PASSWORD FROM customer,auth WHERE customer.EMAIL=auth.email AND customer.PASSWORD=auth.PASSWORD");
```

Then that query is executed with no parameters (all good):

```
newRs=customerPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The bug is here: you supply parameters to the query, but it has no slots for them and you get a **java.sql.SQLException**:

```
customerPreparedStatement.setString(1, customer.getEmail());
customerPreparedStatement.setString(2, customer.getPassword());
```

You should leave **customerPreparedStatement** as is and not attempt to supply parameters it isn't using.  So, in that case you'd drop those two lines doing **customerPreparedStatement.setString** as they can't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I am getting another error now: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: @user3443889 what line does that stack trace mention. The code line as I don't have your files to match line numbers.

Comment: @user3443889 refactoring this code into multiple methods (certainly one for each prepared statement) would really help you isolate the problem.  Are you using an IDE that let's you click a stack trace to get to the source?

Comment: I think this is the line where I am stuck: customerPreparedStatement.setString(1, customer.getEmail());                                                                                      customer is not getting the value of email. I have to get it from auth and compare it with the customer

Comment: @user3443889 what line does the stacktrace indicate? Easier place to start.

Comment: @user3443889 we've solved your original question.  Can you accept this answer and post a new question to do the next increment?  I'm happy to help.

Comment: @user3443889 interesting. That's a surprise. Can you add the modified code you are using to the question so I can compare?  I must be missing something crucial.

Comment: I am giving my editted code here below. I am not able to ask new question, that's why.

Comment: @user3443889 no worries. I'll continue to help here.  A good strategy for fixing that limit is to accept answers and vote up useful things you see.  They'll lift those restrictions pretty quickly. They just need to know you're not a bot :)

Comment: @user3443889 also take a look Jon Skeet's ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and follow it and you can avoid the downvotes people dumped on you here.

Comment: @user3443889 use [GitHub Gist](https//gist.github.com/) to post anonymous gists and share the links here if you can't edit.  I'll transcribe. Shit happens. I can help bridge the gap :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thanks ALain O'Dea, it works just by adding this line:

```
customerPreparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer.EMAIL, customer.PASSWORD, auth.EMAIL, auth.PASSWORD FROM customer,auth WHERE customer.EMAIL=? AND customer.PASSWORD=?");
```

but now I am getting another error. This is my editted code:

CustomerDAO class:

```
  public boolean authenticated(Auth auth) throws AppException {

        Connection con = DBUtil.connectToDB();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        PreparedStatement customerPreparedStatement=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        ResultSet newRs=null;
        Customer customer=new Customer();

        try {
            ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO auth(EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            //if((customer.getEmail().equals(auth.getEmail())) && (customer.getPassword().equals(auth.getPassword())))
            ps.setString(1, auth.getEmail());
            ps.setString(2, auth.getPassword());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            //geting generated key
            rs= ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

**Alain: Delete this:**

```
            customerPreparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer.EMAIL, customer.PASSWORD, auth.EMAIL, auth.PASSWORD FROM customer,auth WHERE customer.EMAIL=? AND customer.PASSWORD=?");
```

**Alain: insert this instead:**

```
            customerPreparedStatement=con.prepareStatement("SELECT customer.EMAIL, customer.PASSWORD, auth.EMAIL, auth.PASSWORD FROM customer,auth WHERE customer.EMAIL=auth.EMAIL AND customer.PASSWORD=auth.PASSWORD");
```

**Alain: and keep this:**

```
           // error is indicating this line
            newRs=customerPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

**Alain: and delete these lines:**

```
            customerPreparedStatement.setString(1, customer.getEmail());
            customerPreparedStatement.setString(2, customer.getPassword());
```

**Alain: and keep the rest:**

```
            if(auth.getEmail().equals(customer.getEmail()) && auth.getPassword().equals(customer.getPassword())){
        //  if(customerPreparedStatement){  


                while(rs.next()){

        //          customer.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                    auth.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                    auth.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));

        //          System.out.print());
                }
            return true;

            }else {
                System.out.print("user doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AppException("Error in authentication", e.getCause());
        }finally{
            DBUtil.closeResources(ps, rs, con);
        }
    }
```

CustomerController Class:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public AppResponse login(Auth auth, @Context HttpServletRequest request){


    AppResponse resp = new AppResponse();
    // generating the common msg for successful/ unsuccessful connection

        //if successful show list
        CustomerDAO customerDAO=new CustomerDAO();


            boolean isAuthenticated;
            try {

               //error is indicating this line
                isAuthenticated = customerDAO.authenticated(auth);
                //creating session
                HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("USER", auth);

                if(isAuthenticated){
                    resp.setMessage("Login is successfull");

                }else{

                    resp.setMessage("Login is failed");
                    resp.setStatus(AppResponse.ERROR);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    //  resp.setPayload(auth);

        //customerDAO.getAll();
    return resp;


}
```

This is the new error is:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2253)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2233)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1976)
        at restaurant.my.dao.CustomerDAO.authenticated(CustomerDAO.java:161)
        at restaurant.my.rest.CustomerController.login(CustomerController.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Now let's fix the followup issue :)

Comment: Check my notes inline above.  I think those steps will get you past the issue.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10205325)

Comment: @PaulHicks very true generally and exactly what I suggested. OP was blocked from asking new questions possibly due to low rep.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I am not getting error now but logically it has some issue. The result is now showing that the customer is not in the database. I think the logic is not going into if statement.